# Windows 7 32-bit IIS session timeout for classic asp

Tags: session, iis, windows-7, asp-classic

I've moved a Classic ASP app from XP/2000 to my Windows 7 Pro box, but the session (specified in the global.asa) is expiring faster. What determines session timeout on a Win 7, IIS box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28WS.10%29.aspx

Let me know if that helps